# polylongdiv style=D error

Tags: polynom

**English translation**

When I use the command `\polylongdiv[style=D]{3x^4+0x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2-x}`, I get the following error:

> ! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of
>   \language@active@arg~.\par
>   ...ngdiv[style=D]{3x^4+0x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2-x} I suspect you have
>   forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop.

I don't know how to fix it.
Could you help me?

**Original text**

Al ejecutar `\polylongdiv[style=D]{3x^4+0x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2-x}` me sale el siguiente error:

> ! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of
>   \language@active@arg~.\par
>   ...ngdiv[style=D]{3x^4+0x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2-x} I suspect you have
>   forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop.

Y no sé como arreglarlo.
Una ayuda?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please use English when posting on this site. Moreover, could you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can reproduce your error and help you?

Comment: Same error. But division is ok. Any clue about this error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, by default, `babel-spanish` makes `~` into a shorthand character used for typing `~n` to give ñ.

Nowadays this is no longer useful, because you can directly input `ñ`.

Add the `es-notilde` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-notilde]{babel}

\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{3x^4+0x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2-x}

\end{document}
```

Actually, if the package used `\nobreakspace` instead of `~`, the problem would not appear.

Proof of concept.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage{polynom}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\pld@ArrangeResult}{~}{\nobreakspace}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{3x^4+0x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2-x}

\end{document}
```